# Insert Caption in Word Using Excel VBA - Position Below (Not Above!)

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am using the following code in Excel to insert a picture into Word. For some reason when the last line runs, the caption is added *above* the picture even though I've marked the position as wdCaptionPositionBelow. Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?

```
Set mypic = my_word.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(Photo_Browser.Photo_Location & "\" & Photo_Browser.Photo_List.List(i), False, True)
my_word.activedocument.InlineShapes(my_word.activedocument.InlineShapes.Count).Select
my_word.Selection.InsertCaption Label:="Figure", TitleAutoText:="InsertCaption1", _
Title:=":", Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow, ExcludeLabel:=0
```

Comment: Check whether `wdCaptionPositionBelow` is `0` or `1`.  If it is `0`, set it to `1` somewhere in your code.  (I'm guessing that you haven't included a reference to the Word Object Library [probably because you are using late-binding and therefore didn't think you needed it] and haven't set all the constants that come with that library.)

Comment: That did it! Thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have not included a reference to the Word Object Library in your project, then none of the constants defined in that library will be available for you to use.

In that library, the constant `wdCaptionPositionBelow` has a value of `1` while the constant `wdCaptionPositionAbove` has a value of `0`.

Without the library reference, your `wdCaptionPositionBelow` will be treated as a variable and, unless you have set its value, it will default to zero - the equivalent of using `wdCaptionPositionAbove` from the library.